How to address multicollinearity when adding random effects in gam model and include random slopes?
I'm working with a generalized additive model (GAM) using the mgcv package in R. My dataset includes measurements collected over several years at different sites. I am interested in x1 and x2 (e.g . temperature and drought), and their interaction effect with y (beetle counts). To reduce multicollinearity, I am using yearly lags (0:3 years back), where I have found the lowest correlation between temperature_lag0 and drought_lag2. Here is a simplified version of my data:
# Sample data
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(
  y = rnbinom(100, mu = 10, size = 1),
  x1 = rnorm(100),
  x2 = rnorm(100),
  site = factor(rep(1:10, each = 10)),
  year = factor(rep(2001:2010, 10))
)

Initially, I fit a model with two smooth terms, and also added an interaction between the two:
library(mgcv)
m1 <- gam(y ~ s(x1) + s(x2) + ti(x1, x2), family = nb(), method = 'REML', data = dat)

I checked the correlation between x1 and x2 and found it to be low (0.2). When I run the model, and check multicollinearity (performance::check_collinearity(m1)), the multicollinearity is still low. However, when I added a random effect for site, the multicollinearity issue appears, and one of my predictor is extremely high (VIF of 17):
m2 <- gam(y ~ s(x1) + s(x2) + s(site, bs = 're'), family = nb(), method = 'REML', data = dat)

How should I proceed further? I am particularly interested in testing the interaction between my factors (e.g. temperature and drought). I want to address this multicollinearity issue and also include the fact that my data are collected over several years. Additionally, I need to include a random slope for x1 by site.
This is what I tried:
# scaling predictors
dat$x1 <- scale(dat$x1)
dat$x2 <- scale(dat$x2)

# Model with random intercepts and slopes
m <- gam(y ~ s(x1, k = 4) + 
             s(x2, k = 4) + 
             s(site, bs = 're') + 
             s(year, bs = 're') +
             ti(x1, x2, bs = 're', k = 4),
         family = nb(),
         method = 'REML',
         data = dat)

Questions:

How can I address the multicollinearity introduced when adding the random effect for site?
Is it meaningful to include the random slope? how to do it, and for which variable?
How can I account for the fact that the data are collected over several years?


You have asked a lot of different complicated questions, and this question could indeed use some more focus, but I will do my best to answer them as much as possible given how difficult modeling GAMs may be.
Very first, don't scale your predictors for GAMs. Full stop. I talk about that briefly here.
To add, one doesn't check for multicollinearity in GAMs, one checks for concurvity, which to simplify a lot is it's nonlinear equivalent (basically one of your smooths can be approximated by a combo of other smooths in the model). Concurvity is straightforwardly checked within mgcv with the concurvity function (see here). As far as what one can do if there is in fact concurvity present, one can find ways to combine the measures in some way (e.g. height and weight combined into BMI) or omit one of the variables if the other is much more theoretically important.
As for whether or not you should add a random slope, that can only be determined by past literature and your best plausible guess about the relationship. So one cannot reasonably determine this unless you have your own guesses about what this would look like. For example, I know that when estimating by-word random intercepts in mixed models which predict reading, the associations between vocab and reading likely vary a lot for subjects, but this would probably vary little for something like age and reading if the model only contains a very limited range of ages. As for how to estimate them, the typical fitting of the spline would be something like s(random.effect, x, bs = "re") where random.effect is just whatever variable that you want the slopes to vary within and x as the effect who's random slope is allowed to vary.
With respect to time-varying variables, your current setup estimates the random deviations in the grand mean by time. However, if you were actually interested in how your DV changes over time, it would probably be better to add it in directly, and perhaps you could have each predictor vary with time by modeling it like so:
  m <- gam(y ~ year + # since this is treated as factor, it has to enter as linear
           s(x1, by = "year", k = 4) + # smooth of x1 varying by year
           s(x2, by = "year", k = 4) + # smooth of x2 varying by year
           ti(x1, x2, by= "year", k = 4) + # smooth interaction by year
           s(site, bs = 're'), # random intercept of site
         family = nb(), 
         method = 'REML',
         data = dat)

However, this will model 10 different curves for both your main effects and interaction, which would be a lot of parameters in your model (and likely would require a lot of data). Perhaps you could just enter time in by itself as s(year) if one isn't interested in how the other predictors vary by year, but otherwise interested in how the DV changes with time.
 m <- gam(y ~ s(year)+ # smooth of year by itself
           s(x1, k = 4) + # smooth of x1 
           s(x2, k = 4) + # smooth of x2 
           ti(x1, x2, k = 4) + # smooth interaction
           s(site, bs = 're'), # random intercept of site
         family = nb(), 
         method = 'REML',
         data = dat)

Others may offer other suggestions, but those are some options for now.
